# A 2's complement conversion

Tags: binary, hex

Honestly I'm doing some homework and got stuck with the 2's complement concept. So my question asked me to find the 2's complement for 492 and -1094(**as 16-bit number**) in both binary and hexadecimal. But I really got confused with the way it works. So I did 492's binary and mine was like **0000 0100 1001 0010** but I really got lost and don't feel right about my answer.. Can someone help me here... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

492 in binary goes to 0001 1110 1100

1*2^8 + 1*2^7 + 1*2^6 + 1*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0

-1094 in binary goes to 0100 0100 0110

The trick to represent a negative number: you have to convert to binary and flip all the digits (0 becomes 1, and 1 becomes 0) and add 1.

Comment: so a positive number's 2's complement dont need conversion? Just simply lays it out in binary form?

Comment: Correct. Positive number just convert to binary straight forward. Negative number you need to flip bits and add 1.

Comment: But the guy above says needs to flip bits and add 1 for 492.. Im really confused..

Comment: That is correct ... If you want are looking for -492. If you want +492, then you just need to convert to binary.

Comment: OK, I see the confusion: 2's complement is the same as representing a negative number. So you are indeed looking for -492, and 1094.

Comment: I mean for 492. Its 2's complement is flip 0001 1110 1100 and then add 1?

Comment: Correct. That is how you calculate 492 complement.

Answer (score 1):

So to calculate 2's complement, you just do the following:

For some number B, invert it's binary representation, and add 1.

For 492:

```
111101100
000010011 <-- invert
000010100 <-- add 1
```

Just do the same for your binary representation of -1094.